# Text size on images for pdf ebooks

Tags: publishing, ebook, electronic-publishing, picture-books

I have designed an ebook using very specific formatting and graphics that need to be maintained. As such, I am converting the individual pages into image files, and then publishing the complete book as a pdf for uploading as an ebook. What point size should the text be on the page images to not be too small for reading on mobile phones, tablets, and e-readers?

Comment: You may lose a lot of readers if you format your book that way.  Whenever I come across an ebook like that I simply delete it and go to find a better one.

Comment: Will you make separate versions for different aspect ratios and screen resolutions? There isn't a good one-font-size-fits-all.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a font size of 12 for the body text and 14-18 for the title.

You may also check some of the suggestions for the font types at https://creativemarket.com/blog/best-fonts-for-ebooks

The same website also has some suggestions about the font sizes, which seem to be matching what I am suggesting.

Comment: Interesting link, thanks.